# what does [rsync: failed to set times on "/."] really means?

Tags: linux, path, rsync

```
sync: failed to set times on "/." (in XXXXXXXXXXX): Operation not permitted (1)
./

sent 483,746 bytes  received 2,706 bytes  324,301.33 bytes/sec
total size is 161,339,379,726  speedup is 331,665.57
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
ERROR: The synchronisation failed.
Done ...
```

I got this weird `"/."` I don't get what is this path or even what it refers to.
Since it's an error 23, I can confirm that other files are well transferred. All have different rights and groups that are indeed compatible.

Also I do **not** want to use `--omit-dir-times`.

So how do I fix this ? Where is or what is `"/."`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I fix this ?

Possible run the command as `root` or as an owner of current directory.

> Where is or what is "/."?

This path seems to be absolute, it's the file system root directory - `/`.

From [wikipedia path (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)):

> Two dots ("..") point upwards in the hierarchy, to indicate the parent directory; one dot (".") represents the current directory itself.

Comment: I'm rsync-ing a specific folder from server A to a specific folder on server B, so you mean that rsync is trying to change time of the absolute path of the folder on server B? or do you mean that it is trying to rsync outside the targeted folder on server B and trying to change the time of the root directory?

Comment: `so you mean that rsync is trying to change time of the absolute path of the folder on server B?` Most probably the modification timestamp of the root folder. See `stat /`. `do you mean that it is trying to rsync outside the targeted folder on server B` I do not know which folder is targeted. Could be `/.` is relative path in rsync message - there's `./` right below. So it could be setting the modification timestamp of the "targeted directory".

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Do you think it could be from my rsyncd.conf? the folder path is set like this: 'path = /mnt/BackupDrive/XXXXXXXXXXX/'

Answer (score 2):

The destination dir/folder does not allow modification of the specific folder.

eg.
rsync: [generator] failed to set times on "/mnt/tmp/.": Operation not permitted

I was mounting a ISO or UDF file image through the loop filesystem to /mnt/tmp.  The required folder permissions were not permissive enough, and should be changed prior to mounting the filesystem to /mnt/tmp.

Although just a warning, still interferes with interpreting the command return value upon exit of the command.

Change the dir/folder permissions prior to mounting or working with the folder, or add yourself to the group with appropriate group permissions.

## chmod -R a+rwX /mnt/tmp

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem: In my case the cause was some bad extended filesystem attribute setting.

Specifically,  I had set "chattr +i /path/to/somedir", by mistake, and therefore made somedir (and content) unwritable. To fix, use "chattr -i  /path/to/somedir

It may not be so obvious that attributes are the problem. The permissions may be all good (say rwx), but attributes overrule those regular unix permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had not reconfigured my repository to use ssh.  The error listed is what I got.  I then changed my .git/config file to use ssh: and it cleared up.